# Why are 3D vectors in C++ larger in RAM than a 1D vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I've discovered by accident that an STL vector defined as follows:

```
vector < float > test;
test.resize(10000 * 10000 * 5);
```

Uses up significant less space in RAM than the following definition:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector< float > > > test;

test.resize(10000);
for(int i = 0;i <  10000;i++)
{
test[i].resize(10000);
for(int j = 0;j <  10000;j++)
{
test[i][j].resize(5);
}
}
```

The linear vector method (top one) uses the correct amount of RAM (2Gb) as would be calculated by hand.  So my question is, why does a 3D vector use up way more RAM than a linear one, I found it was significantly more in this example (about 4Gb).

Comment: Why are you passing floating-point values to `resize`?

Comment: laziness mainly, is that relevant?

Comment: The first one uses one block of memory. All you need is one block big enough rather than having to find craploads of smaller blocks scattered throughout memory, not to mention storing pointers to chunks of memory that have more pointers to other places. 10000 pointers to 10000 pointers each is probably 800MB.

Comment: There is a big difference between creating 10,000 floats and 10,000 vector objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector class uses up memory to hold onto additional pointers. When you allocate as a 1D vector, you only have the 1 pointer and big block of memory it points to. In the vector of vector of vector's case, you have 10,000 * 10,000 * 5 vectors, each with a 4 byte pointer, taking up 2 billion extra bytes, just to hold onto location information.

**EDIT**

As Andrey pointed out in the comments, you are not actually setting up 10,000 * 10,000 * 5 vectors, rather:

1D - the top level vector sets aside space for 10,000 vectors beneath it

2D - each of those 10,000 vectors sets up another 10,0000 vectors

3D - the final level is just the actual data so...

you have 10,000 inital vectors, and the 10,000 * 10,000 vectors below for a total of 100,010,000 vectors. Another user mentioned about 20 bytes of space taken by each vector (for the memory pointer as well as other members in the class, like size, capacity and what not) so you end up with about 2 billion bytes.

Comment: So in 1D Vector it use block of memory + 1 pointer, in 3D Vector, it use: Block of memory + (1 + 10000 + 10000) pointers.

Comment: Actually, only 1 + 10.000 + 10.000 * 10.000 = 100.010.001 vectors. Each, however, holds two pointers (or a pointer and a size), so its some 800MB on a 32-bit machine.

Comment: The rest are explained by the fact that most implementations will round 5*sizeof(float) to 32 bytes. That makes as much as 12 * 100.000.000 = 1200MB overhead.

Answer (score 3):

In the former case you have:

```
sizeof(vector<float>)                  // outermost vector
  + 10000 * 10000 * 5 * sizeof(float)  // xyz space
```

In the latter you have:

```
sizeof(vector<vector<vector<float>>>)      // outermost vector
  + 10000 * sizeof(vector<vector<float>>)  // x axis
  + 10000 * 10000 * sizeof(vector<float>)  // xy plane
  + 10000 * 10000 * 5 * sizeof<float>      // xyz space
```

The typical value for `sizeof(vector<T>)` for any `T` is `3 * sizeof(T*)`, which is also, I believe, the minimal value allowed by the standard—capacity must be distinct from size because `reserve()` must change the value of `capacity()` but not of `size()`.

Comment: How does a two pointer vector manage all 3 of begin, end and capacity?  Also, in practice, allocation blocks themselves have overhead.

Comment: @Yakk: You’re right, I second-guessed myself. Fixed.

Comment: well, the vector could cheat and use the information in the "malloc"'d block to calculate capacity...

Answer (score 0):

The vector class has some additional overhead. There is at a minimum a pointer and a field for the size. In MS visual studio sizeof(std::vector) is 20 or 24 (with iterator debugging enabled). The actual size is going to be implementation dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Each vector object has an overhead - as they can be variable length so need to have pointers to the start, size of the used bit and its capacity.

If you have a fixed size 3d shape where the height, width and length is know you can convert it into a 1D array. This would be the most efficent.

To do this given x, y, z you find the index as x + width * ((z * height) + y) will do the conversion.